# hotdeploy / hotswap classes using wildfly maven docker intellij

Tags: java, maven, docker, intellij-idea, wildfly

I have a current setup of intellij 2016 which compiles my java files on the fly. Due to some configuration in intellij it is possible to propagate any changes directly to tomcat. This way I don't have to manually build a new application and deploy it to tomcat which increases user productivity.

We want to remove tomcat and start using wildfly10 but also keep the hotdeploy functionality. On top of that the wildfly server will be hosted in a docker container.

So what I did is that I mounted the wildfly/standalone/deployment/myapp.war using docker to my host directory myapp/target/myapp.war. In addition I configured a jboss remote server configuration with remote stating set to same file system and let maven build an exploded war. This way if a maven build is performed, the contents of the target/myapp.war directory is directly available in my docker container. When I run the container and perform a new maven package, I do see that wildfly states that the new changes are found and redeploying has succeeded. Unfortunately this only goes well once or two times in a row.

So coming from the tomcat hotdeploy where no maven build was involved and any changes where directly available in tomcat, I'm wondering if the same can be achieved with the setup: intellij, maven, wildfly and docker. So if a change of a java file in intellij is compiled and pushed to wildfly without redeploying or maven build?

Answer (score 0):

Wild-fly - eclipse supports 100 % Hot Code replacement

1. you have to start web-app in debugging mode .
2. For every change in java code just do a maven install and refresh
   the target .

Limitations :

1. you can only replace statements in method .
2. you are not allowed to change whole class and new methods .